# Xamarin Forms ToolbarItem poor animation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I´m developing a cross platform aplication on Xamarin Forms. I´m using MasterDetailPage type navigation. I added a Toolbar to a content page and set the `Order` property to 'Secondary' so it appears on a menu just on the right.
When I press the ToolbarItem it makes a very poor transition "flying" to the top-left part of the screen before it dissapears. Is there anyway of modify this animation or just remove it?.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an answer for this issue. By just adding the following line to the `AndroidManifest.xml` there were no more sloppy animations:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Comment: What disadvantages does it have to switch of hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is kind of late, but I found the answer to this problem))
Basically it is more of a bug rather than animation. It happens when there is no time for toolbar menu to close before navigating to a new page.
So in my project I fixed it just by doing a little delay (~200 ms, maybe it can be even less) to give the menu time for closing itself and navigating to some new page after delay (both delay and navigation should happen on secondary thread so you don`t block the UI or you will end up waiting for delay and having the same problem as before).

Comment: So you delay opening the new page? Did you do some UX tests if that has bad influences?